# iPad 2 is not getting detected by xcode4.3

Tags: macos, ios5, xcode4.3

I was able to run my projects in iPad and iPhone using the xcode 4.3 till yesterday. But today when I tried, the XCode is not getting connected with the iPad, and it is getting connected with iPhone.
I have checked the deployment target, provisioning profile, all these things are correct, and working fine in iPhone. In the organizer an orange indicator is showing instead of green symbol while connecting. I have restarted both the system and iPad several times and checked, not get solved.
If anybody having idea about this then please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade you Xcode or  if you have another computer which contains xcode 4.5, detect your device on that computer this will also detect your device on computer with xcode 4.3.
I also had same problem and this works for me.

Comment: I have checked this and device is getting connected with xcode 4.5 in another computer but not in xcode 4.3 in my computer

Comment: what you set ios Deployment Taget. set this 4.0 from build setting -> project-> info -> ios Deployment Taget